# Magento - where is getEmail() defined?

Tags: php, magento-1.8, magic-methods

You can find out the e-mail of the logged in user by using the following code:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$mail = $customer->getEmail();
```

How to find out where `getEmail()` is defined?

I searched in `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Resource\Customer.php` but there is no function called `getEmail()`.

I only found this:

[image: _beforeSave method definition]

So I tracked it back with NetBeans, and found the definition for `Varien_Object` in `lib\Varien\Object.php`.

But in there is no function `getEmail()` either.

I searched the whole project for the string `public function getEmail()`,

This is the result:

```
$ grep -iR "public function getEmail()"
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Send.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/core/_193_Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Send.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/core/_193_Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/core/_193_Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/_core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Send.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/_core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php:    public function getEmail()
app/code/_core/Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Payone/Api/Request/Parameter/Authorization/PersonalData.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Payone/Api/Request/Parameter/CreateAccess/PersonalData.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Payone/Api/Request/Parameter/ManageMandate/PersonalData.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Payone/Api/Request/Parameter/Vauthorization/PersonalData.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Zend/Gdata/App/Extension/Person.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Who.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Zend/Service/ReCaptcha/MailHide.php:    public function getEmail()
lib/Zend/View/Helper/Gravatar.php:    public function getEmail()
```

Comment: method not exists but you can create your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wont find `getEmail()` definition because it doesn't exist.

As you can see in the piece of code you are sharing, `$customer` is an instance of a `Varien_Object`. That class is defined in `lib\Varien\Object.php`.

If you peek there, you'll see that the method isn't defined either... but that's because for better or worse Magento takes advantage of PHP's [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

When a non-existing method is called on this `$customer` instance, `__call()` is executed instead.

This is the method definition for `Varien_Object::_call()`:

```
/**
 * Set/Get attribute wrapper
 *
 * @param   string $method
 * @param   array $args
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            return $data;
        case 'set' :
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            return $result;
        case 'uns' :
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            return $result;
        case 'has' :
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

From here on, the logic is pretty simple. Since `$method` will be `getEmail`, the first branch of the switch will be executed, and `$key` will be got from the method name (skipping the first three characters, since they must necessarily be "get", "set", "uns", or "has") and in this case it'll become "email".